# Resource not found Face API 1.0

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

for the love of my life I just can not figure out why my jason format are all ways wrong , I am using Microsoft Face API 1.0 to create a person within the group

here is my code

```
protected async void btnAddFaces_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        string personGroupId = txtFriendList.Text.ToLower();
        string persons = txtfriendName.Text.ToLower();
        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add
         ("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{YourKey}");

        // Request parameters

        var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/
         persongroups/wowlist/persons?" + queryString;
        // HttpResponseMessage response;
        // not sure but I think here is my problem 
        string body = "{\"name\":\"" + "waheed" + "," + "\"}";
        // Request body
        using (var content = new StringContent
        (body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {

            await client.PutAsync(uri, content)
                .ContinueWith(async responseTask =>
                {
                    var responseBody = await responseTask.Result
                    .Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    txtFaceList.Text = responseBody.ToString();

                });
        }// end of using statement 
}
```

what should happen is a HTTP verb status OK 200 should be return back , all I get is

```
{ "error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "The requested resource was not found." } }
```

I look at my previous post apply the same approach and it just does not work. can someone point me to the correct direction other than jumping off the roof.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong HTTP verb.  In this [case](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523c) you want to use POST, not PUT.  Therefore you need to change the client call to something like:

```
await client.PostAsync(uri, content)
    .ContinueWith(async responseTask =>
    {
        var responseBody = await responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        txtFaceList.Text = responseBody.ToString();
    });
```

Comment: Hi Cthrash I have try that and it still return back resource not found. thanks for your help and support

Comment: Are you certain that your persongroup `wowlist` exists?  You have to create one first if you haven't.

Comment: Yes I have check it via get group list it definitely exists

Comment: recheck and re-ran the code again still not good , I created my personGroup by this url link https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244

Comment: Strange.  I tried your code, more or less verbatim, with PutAsync replaced with PostAsync, and the code works as expected.

Comment: I am going to go online and delete all the groups again and see what happens , could it be because I am using .aspx page  ? how did you test the code above ? was it in Windows Application or ASP.net , need to start comparing how your setup was with mine as this could be the problem . thanks once again for aiding me

Comment: Not sure what to say here , I had to clear out all of my groups via delete HTTP verb and then created a new group that is personGroupID follow creating a new person that is personId . so thank you cthrash for your support this credit goes to you  as PostAsync() was the key fix to the problem as well as what I had to do.